# Array of struct objects - Thread safety

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a global array of struct objects that is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. However there is a guarantee that the individual data members of the struct object(at a particular array index) accessed by two different threads at a time will always be different.

**My question is whether I need to have a mutex lock on this global array for its access or not.**

My struct looks like this:

```
struct data{
   string a;
   int b;
   uint16_t c;
};
```

**EDIT:**

I have a multithreaded UDP server program that creates a fixed number of threads and does recvfrom() block on the same global UDP socket. Whichever thread receives the datagram first, would process that datagram. In this situation, in order to facilitate the storage of client data, I have this global array of objects. In my case, the processing on the data members would happen in this order: `string a, int b, uint16_t c`. No two threads would access the same data member of the same object, because client won't send request for `item b` until it receives response for `item a` and the array is indexed by the client_number.

Comment: How do you know two different threads won't be using same object at the same time?

Comment: @Mr. E - indexes might be distributed on the threads by even/oddness, by lower third, middle third, upper third, etc.

Comment: In that case two different threads will NEVER use the same object, but OP is saying that two threads won't use same object at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if there is a 100% guarentee that two different threads is not touching the same location in memory at the same time there should be no need for using mutex lock.

However if you are only 99.99% certain that it will not be touched the same time, you definitly need a mutex lock.

On the other hand, will the use of a mutex lock impact your application in any way? Because, if it isn't it might be worth adding a mutex for safety in case something isn't running exactly as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

> However there is a guarantee that the individual data members of the struct object accessed by two different threads at a time will always be different.

How do you guarantee that if not by synchronizing your threads somehow?

If you mean that *thread 'a'* **always** only accesses *member 'a'* while *thread 'b'* **always** only accesses *member 'b'*, then you won't need a lock or other synchronization.

Otherwise, you *will* need some synchronization. A *mutex* for the struct object would be one way to do it. The guarantee you mention could be given by having *mutexes* for the individual struct members or *critical sections* for code parts accessing one of them.

So, if you really can give this guarantee, no, you don't need another *mutex*. But that would imply you already *have* some synchronization in place.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a chance thread 1 will ever need to read updates made by thread 2, you will have to use some sort of syncronization - either atomic access or mutexes. Without those, updates might not be visible.

Answer (score -1):

Make some padding within structure to ensure that accessing two neighbouring instances do not overlap. Consider:

```
struct data th[2];
```

Imagine symbolic layout in memory: `0000011111`. If first thread starts writing th[0] and second reads th[1] some might overlap depending on alignment. Consider alignment of 8 symbols: `WWWWWWWW111`. Then first two symbols of second structure would not be consistent on read before ending write and restoring `WWWWW11111`.